# How to make Qt read ISO-8859-15 encoded XML on Windows?

Tags: c++, xml, windows, qt, encoding

I have this very simple test program:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QXmlStreamReader>

auto main(int argc, char * argv[]) -> int {
    auto Application = QCoreApplication{argc, argv};
    auto File = QFile{"iso-8859-15.xml"};
    File.open(QIODeviceBase::OpenModeFlag::ReadOnly);
    
    auto StreamReader = QXmlStreamReader{File.readAll()};
    while(StreamReader.atEnd() == false) {
        StreamReader.readNext();
    }
    if(StreamReader.hasError() == true) {
        qDebug() << StreamReader.errorString();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Given an appropriate, correctly encoded XML file `iso-8859-15.xml` with the processing instruction `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="yes"?>`:

- when I execute the resulting program on Linux, it finishes without error.
- when I execute the resulting program on Windows, I get this error message:

```
"Encoding ISO-8859-15 is unsupported"
```

Why is that? Do I need to install or deploy any additional Qt libraries? Is this simply unsupported on Windows or are there any workarounds for this?

This question relates to Qt 6. So QTextCodec is only available through the Core5Compat module. QXmlStreamReader does not use QTextCodec, but QStringDecoder.

Comment: You may display list of [availableCodecs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextcodec.html#availableCodecs) on both platforms...

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42. I forgot to mention in the question, that this relates to Qt 6, where QTextCodec is from the Core5Compat library. QXmlStreamReader does not use the QTextCodec class however, so even after linking the library, I can enumerate the ISO-8859-15 codec but it doesn't help alleviate the problem.

Comment: You already read entire file to memory. Just convert to desired encoding in memory, and give that to XML reader.

Comment: @hyde Yes, that is my solution currently. What made me post this question was just, that Linux behaves differently, even though Qt is on the same version. I had hopes that it was just a configuration or usage issue.